# Create arraylist of availableCoordinates

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, coordinates, spawn

I am currently making a snake game and I don't want the apple to spawn inside my snake. I tried to fix this by doing this:

```
    ArrayList<Coordinate> availableCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();

    public void Coordinates() {


        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquaresY; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSquaresX; j++) {
                availableCoordinates.add(new Coordinate(j*squareSize, i*squareSize, snake.get(0).color));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < availableCoordinates.size()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < snake.size() - 1; j++) {
                if (availableCoordinates.get(i).xPos == snake.get(j).xPos && availableCoordinates.get(i).yPos == snake.get(j).yPos){
                    availableCoordinates.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

However only 1 value is getting removed even though it should be 3 that are getting removed, and I don't know why.

Comment: Why do you substract 1 from your `list.size()` in the 3rd and 4th `for`? That should ignor the last element of each list

Comment: Just from the glance, you are not looping through the entire list, you are looping until last but 1 element. It should be (i < list.size) and not (i < list.size() - 1)

Comment: Removing an item from the list while iterating with indexes reduces the size by 1 each time and the value you actually dont want to remove might get removed

Comment: well I took -1 because it's an array and arrays always start from 0. So if the snake is 3 rectangles long then the size would be 3 but the array would be 2. Why is that wrong?

Comment: and even if I remove the -1 it still only removed 2 values even though 3 must get removed

Comment: @Symet3 You are looping a List and not an Array

Comment: Ok but It still doesn't work. Only 2 values are getting removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over `availableCoordinates` and inside this loop you remove items from it.
So after you removed an element the following elements get a new index.
The loop index is incremented anyways so you jump over an element after removing.

I would not add all coordinates to the list and then remove the used ones.
While filling your `availableCoordinates` check if this field is free:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquaresY; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSquaresX; j++) {
        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(j*squareSize, i*squareSize, snake.get(0).color);
        if (!snake.contains(c)) {
            availableCoordinates.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

assuming that `Coordinate#equals` only checks `xPos` and `yPos`.

EDIT:
If you cannot use `contains` you have to create a 3rd `for` level to iterate through your snake's elements:

```
boolean doIt;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquaresY; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSquaresX; j++) {
        Coordinate c = new Coordinate(j*squareSize, i*squareSize, snake.get(0).color);
        // reset flag for each coordinate
        doIt = true;
        for (Coordinate bodyElement : snake) {
            if (c.xPos == bodyElement.xPos && c.yPos == bodyElement.yPos) {
                // coordinate is used by snake
                doIt = false;
                // no need to check other body elements
                break;
            }
        }
        if (doIt) {
            availableCoordinates.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello this is not removing any values. When I do "!(snake.get(x).xPos == c.xPos && snake.get(x).yPos == c.yPos)" instead of snake.contains(c) it works but then I can't check all the snake elements.

Comment: @Symet3 see EDIT: a new `for` level is needed

Answer (score 1):

Use removeIf() to remove from the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveItemsFromListIfPresentInAnotherList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Coordinate> availableCoords = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Coordinate> snakeCoords = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //..

        for (Coordinate snakeCoordinate : snakeCoords) {
            availableCoords.removeIf(availableCoord ->
                    (snakeCoordinate.getX() == availableCoord.getX() && snakeCoordinate.getY() == availableCoord.getY()));
        }
    }
}

class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```